# Django query for many-to-one relation with no instances of the foreign-key relationship

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

I have a many-to-one relationship between submissions and assignments (a student may have multiple submissions for a single assignment).  I would like to create a query that shows the assignments with no associated submissions.

My models.py includes:

```
class Assignment(model.Model):
    student=models.ForeignKey("Student")
    timeStarted=models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Submission(models.Model):
    assignment=models.ForeignKey("Assignment")
    timeSubmitted=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    answerFile=models.FileField(upload_to="/%Y/%m/%d")
```

Thank you for any help for the syntax for this query.

Comment: Spend some time reading Django's documentation on field lookups; you should understand all the capabilities: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups. I've linked to the relevant section, but that whole page is worth a thorough read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Assignment.objects.filter(submission__isnull=True)
```